# FFT Algorithm for an interpolating polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm trying to use the Fast Fourier transform algorithm to determine the trigonometric interpolating polynomial of degree $16$ for $f(x) = x^2\cos(x)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$

I see a computer result in my book, but don't understand how to do it by hand.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some information about the result and / or the algorithm that is used in your book?

Answer (score 2):

First, note the difference between a [Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of a function which is a continuous expression. and a [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) which is a specific algorithm for computing a [discrete numerical version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) of the said transformation.

The trigonometric interpolating polynomial of degree $16$ is most easily expressed as a [Fourier Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series). Since the function is even, only $\cos(nx)$ terms appear:
$$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos(n x)$$
$$a_n = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)dx$$
In your case,
$$a_{16} = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x^2\cos(16x)\cos(x)dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x^2(\cos(15x)+\cos(17x))dx$$
And then use integration by parts to show that:
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x^2\cos(mx)dx = \left.\frac{2 x \cos (m x)}{m^2}+\frac{(m^2 x^2-2) \sin (m x)}{m^3} \right|^\pi_\pi$$

Since $m$ is odd, the $\sin$ terms drop off, and we get:
$$a_{16} = \left.\frac{x \cos (15 x)}{15^2} + \frac{x \cos (17 x)}{17^2} \right|^\pi_\pi = -2 \pi/225 - 2 \pi/289 = -1028 \pi/65025$$
$$ \sim -0.04966$$

Comment: can you please show how to do this via hand computation? Thanks

Comment: @BuddyHolly - done.